# Math.Round in a textbox

Tags: c#, textbox

I want to Math.Round my textboxtext. How can I do that?
This is my code:

```
Textboxtext.Text = Math.Round.Convert.ToString(pay, 2);
```

Comment: Is `pay` an `int` or `string`?

Answer (score 3):

Call `ToString` *after* rounding the number:

```
Textboxtext.Text = Math.Round(pay, 2).ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead of Math.Round

```
Textboxtext.Text = pay.ToString("#.##");
```

It rounds the value and convert to a string.